# captures specific value from Kafka topics json file

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to capture the topic name - `TEST2` from the following `topic-json` file

```
more topic-json
{
 "version":1,
 "partitions":[
{"topic":"TEST2","partition":0,"replicas":[1003,1002,1001]},
{"topic":"TEST2","partition":1,"replicas":[1001,1003,1002]},
{"topic":"TEST2","partition":2,"replicas":[1002,1001,1003]},
{"topic":"TEST2","partition":3,"replicas":[1003,1001,1002]},
{"topic":"TEST2","partition":4,"replicas":[1001,1002,1003]},
{"topic":"TEST2","partition":5,"replicas":[1002,1003,1001]},
.
.
.
```

so far I wrote the following in order to get the first elements but not succeeded to print only the `TEST2` name

```
/tmp/jq -s '{ partitions: map(.partitions[1]) }'  topic-json
{
  "partitions": [
    {
      "topic": "TEST2",
      "partition": 1,
      "replicas": [
        1001,
        1003,
        1002
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output

```
TEST2
```

Comment: Try `jq -r '.partitions[1].topic' topic-json`

Comment: Please don't blindly apply tags. This has nothing to do with Bash, Kafka or Linux-specific APIs. This is just JSON processing with `jq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that .partitions is a non-empty array, you could go with:

```
jq -r '.partitions[0].topic' topic-json
```

Otherwise, consider alternatives such as:

```
jq -r 'first(.partitions[].topic)' topic-json
```

---

Your use of `jq -s` suggests that perhaps you might ultimately want the distinct topics, in which case you could go with something like:

```
jq -r '[.partitions[].topic] | unique[]' topic-json
```